# Code misbehaving: Trying to search an array for string and print contents of each line

Tags: java

This is a portion of a beginner Java homework assignment.

This particular portion requires the program to read a text file of names (*"Banner, Bruce"*, *"Stark, Tony"*, etc.), sort it alphabetically, and allow a user to display the entire contents of the file, or search each line of the file for a string of text ("ban" brings up every line that contains the characters "ban." Banner, Bancroft, etc.).

The program functioned until I tried to implement the alphabetizing portion of the assignment. Then it's just been problematic from there. I have spent hours online to try and get past this last hurdle to complete my assignment.

This is a class separate from the main method. The assignment required that the write-to-file and read-from-file portions be separate classes from the main method.

EDITED: Tom's comments got me thinking, so I poked at the code, a lot and stopped trying to make the alphabetizing and array portion into its own method. I was able to get the code to alphabetize the `ArrayList` and only print out one time instead of thirteen or with other weirdness. This has caused a new problem, however, and broken the search portion. This functionality was previously working, but that was when I had the `if/else if` statement surrounded by a `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)` loop.  That loop is what was making the alphabetizing array print out a gazillion times. Now without the loop, the program is only searching the first line of the text file (it finds *"Banner, Bruce"*, but won't find *"Stark, Tony"*). I've tried to put the while loop into the `else-if` statement, but then it kept finding *"Banner, Bruce"* infinitely.

I've been poking at it for several hours now, I've gone over several loop tutorials (including for array lists) and I can't figure out the correct syntax tow to make the search portion loop through each line of the file and then print each line that contains the user input that doesn't result in it just printing the whole array list, or printing one line ad infinitum.

My Edited Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class readPortion 
{
    readPortion() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        //calling the file, I think? Program doesn't work without it.
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("name_list.txt"));
        String line = br.readLine();
        String searchWord;

        //what are we searching for?
        System.out.print("Enter a string of characters in which to search by or enter \"all names\" for a complete list: ");
        searchWord = gatherInput();

        System.out.println("Search Results include: ");

        //making an arraylist out of the file
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("name_list.txt"));
        while (inFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            list.add(inFile.nextLine());
        }
        Collections.sort(list);

        //conducting the if/then for "all names" or "search"
        if (searchWord.equalsIgnoreCase("all names")) 
        {
            for (String temp : list)
            {
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
        }
            // else if the user entered string, search up each line... WHY YOU BREAK?!
        else if (line.toLowerCase().contains(searchWord.toLowerCase()))
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            br.close();
        }

        //we're done printing stuff from the file.
        System.out.println("End!");
    }

    //method outside of main, gathering user input with a scanner
    public static String gatherInput()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String user_input = scan.nextLine();
        return user_input;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder why you read the "name_list" in your `alphabetize` method. Can you explain your thoughts behind that?

Comment: What I mean is: you're currently reading the file in the `readPortion` method, so why do you read it "parallel" in another method?

Comment: To be honest, because when I looked online for how to alphabetize the lines in a file, that's how the code looked. This is the 6th lab assignment for my class-- there's no book and the professor just gives a quick crash course on stuff before setting us loose. I've been able to get every assignment to work, with full points (thanks to many tutorials online and the oracle site), but I feel like I have NO idea what I'm doing, why half this stuff works and I can't conceptualize how to manipulate the code.  I'm not even sure how to go about executing the alphabetization without that (I'll go try).

Comment: Can you please edit your post and question to be more specific? It's a little confusing as to which specific things need solving.

Comment: Well, since Bohemians comment may helped you to solve your current problem, you should also work one the problem that you don't understand what you're doing there. Since you're new this is pretty normal, but you shouldn't leave it at that. Do you have classmates to work in a group? Can the prof give better explanations and not just a crash course? Also try to get used with the _debugger_ of your IDE. Then "debug" working programs and step through the code lines, to see what exactly happens there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from (unnecessarily) opening the input file multiple times, your logic flaw is here:

```
if (searchWord.equalsIgnoreCase("all names")) {
    for(String temp: list) {
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
} else if (line.toLowerCase().contains(searchWord.toLowerCase())) {
        System.out.println(line);
}
```

It should be:

```
for(String line: list) {
    if (searchWord.equalsIgnoreCase("all names") || line.toLowerCase().contains(searchWord.toLowerCase()))
        System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Comment: Gah, thank you! Now I'll work on figuring out how to not open the input file repeatedly. Thank you for pointing out the error, and showing me how it ought to look.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood your problem, may be you want to do something like this -

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner scan= new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("//your filepath")));
    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        list.add(scan.nextLine());
    }
    scan.close();
    Collections.sort(list);

    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the name you want to search");
    String type=s.nextLine();

    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("all names")){
        System.out.println(list);
    }
    else{
        for(String str:list){
            if(str.toLowerCase().contains(type.toLowerCase())){
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("************");
    System.out.println("Thats all we have !!!");
    s.close();
}
```